# How to remove unwanted html code from strings in python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to clean items on my python list which look like this at the moment:

```
emails = ['<div dir="auto">Hi,</div><div dir="auto"><br></div><div dir="auto"> I would like to ask about. Some more text here...<br></div><div dir="auto"><br></div><div dir="auto">Regards</div> <br> <span style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.8px;background-color:rgb(255,255,255)"></span><html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <title>My Title</title> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <style type="text/css">/* e-mail bugfixes */ #outlook a {padding:0 0 0 0;} .ReadMsgBody {width:100%;} .ExternalClass {width:100%; line-height:100%;}  sup, sub {vertical-align:baseline; position:relative; top:-0.4em;}  sub {top:0.4em;}   /* General classes */  body {width:100% !important; margin:0;...',...]
```

my goal is to ideally keep only the text that is in between html tags and remove all the html code for each item on the list

I've been trying using BeautifulSoup however it mostly only removed brackets from html tags and kept the rest instead of giving me only the actual email content:

```
noHtml = []    
for x in emails:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(x)
    noHtml.append(soup.get_text())
```

Would someone be able to help with this? Any possible way I can achieve it in Python? (not necessarily with BS) Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print` doesn't return anything. so your `noHtml` array would be blank. use `append` to insert text in the array.

Comment: can you edit and include the full html in that list, with all the tags. In other words, include what was excluded with the `...` part

Comment: To remove html tags you can use regex. e.g.  
`clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
re.sub(clean, '', email)`